# Calling a C++ shared Library in Ruby

Tags: c++, ruby, linux, unix, dll

I have a shared library "**mylib.so**" which was written in **C++** and I would like to make an application in Ruby that calls the library functions.

I researched and found **FFI** (https://github.com/ffi/ffi) and it only works with a C library. With **Rice** (https://rubygems.org/gems/rice/versions/2.1.0) only I found tutorial that I need to change the source code of the library, but I do not have access to this code.

Is there any way to implement a **C++** library in my **Ruby** code to use its functions?

Answer (score 1):

When you say you don't have access to the code, you mean that you do not have access to the headers of the library? If you do not have access to the headers defining classes, prototyping functions and exposing some API, then you wouldn't be able to actually bind this library to any other segment of code, whether the latter is written in `c++`, `python`, `ruby` or whatever.

If you *do* have access to the headers of the library, then you can easily use `rice-ruby` to build a `ruby` wrapper - by following the instructions [here](https://github.com/jasonroelofs/rice/blob/master/README.md). You need only the headers and an up-to-date version of your library in order to do a proper wrap. Feel free to better define your problem and I'll try to help.